# android convert fragment activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I found the following code (item 2) on google maps to display the device current location... works great... however how do convert it to a fragment to add it to existing main activity. Most of my code uses fragment as follows (item 1):

ITEM 1

```
switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new login_login();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new login_create();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new calendar();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new live_webcast();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new live_webcast_archive();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new find_us();
                break;
```

ITEM 2

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Maps2Activity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationProvider.LocationCallback {


    // Use Location Provider
    public static final String TAG = Maps2Activity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mLocationProvider.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocationProvider.disconnect();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the find_us.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the find_us from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the find_us.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        commonfunc.myprint("Lat/Lon______________: " + " " + currentLatitude + "-" +currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Fragment with a SupportMapFragment Widget, like this:

MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Get location
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        LatLng here = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(here).title("YOU ARE HERE").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(here, 14));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

R.layout.fragment_maps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/contenitor_child"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

remember to add gms
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'